# How do you name a class when you store the name in a variable first?

Tags: c++, class

I was just curious about this one day.

Is it possible to save a variable with user input and then create an instance of a class with that variable as the name?

After that, is it possible to save the class name in a variable from within the class?

Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class example {
public:

};

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?  ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!";
    //I would like to create an instance of the class here with a name of what they inputted into the variable name
}
```

Again this is purely for curiosity, but I would really love to know if this is actually possible.

Comment: But the user can't see your code, so what's the point?

Comment: The point is that I could theoretically look at a server and have all of the class names listed there.

Comment: Have you tried storing it in an array? And having a variable containing the array index?

Comment: You're not getting the point.  I'm trying to actually name the class instance the thing that they enter into the console.

Comment: The "server"? This is just a program. It's compiled *once and once only* into a binary that you then execute. At that point class names are entirely meaningless and variables are long, long gone.

Comment: We get the point. It seems like you don't understand what happens when a program is compiled. That's why we're really confused. It's because what you're asking for makes no sense.

Comment: No, not possible. The closest thing to what you want is a manually constructed `std::map<std::string, some function pointer>`, which maps class names to functions that can be used to construct the classes. And you'll have to come up with a way to store the constructed objects that doesn't depend on their type (`std::any`?).

Comment: Once again, this is completely theoretical @tadman.   I could potentially incorporate this into a larger project is all that I mean.

Comment: If I were to try and rework this question, do my best to interpret it, this sounds like "How do I dynamically instantiate different classes based on user input and store them into some kind of data structure?" That is a lot more specific, but is that what you're saying?

Comment: This site isn't about theoretical situations, it's about code you can show us that needs help to get working. *What problem are you trying to solve?* You may be well off in the weeds with this approach because a simpler solution is at hand if you can express the goals.

Comment: Yes it is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Can these objects inherit from the same base class? Could you override with `virtual` functions? If so, `std::map<std::string, MyBaseClass*>` could do it. This creates a look-up table of sorts using string keys, so you can keep track of the objects you've created and the names they're given. You can fancy that up using wrappers on the pointer to automatically de-allocate, etc.

Comment: So if the user enters "hello", you want to create a variable named "hello"? I don't think that's how C++ works...

Comment: C++ is not javascript ;)

Comment: I was literally just asking if it was possible.  I didn't know that I wasn't supposed to ask theoretical questions.

Comment: @tadman Let's be honest, half of the language-lawyer questions are theoretical, yet we do allow them. OP's question looks fine to me. Yes, they're not aware of limitations of C++, but it's not a crime.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Re-tagged accordingly then.

Comment: @tadman Huh? But this isn't a language-lawyer question (I didn't say it is, I only mentioned language-lawyer questions as an example of valid theoretical questions). I'm sure OP will take our word for it not being possible (at least directly), without asking for a citation from the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    std::string name; //property
    Person(std::string n) : name(n) {}; //class constructor
};

int main() {
    std::string userName;

    std::cin >> userName;

    Person user(userName);

    std::cout << user.name;
}
```

This will output the name that is typed as input, showing that the `name` property of the object `user` (that is an instance of `Person`) has been changed to that input.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was referring to. Read the comments for more info

Comment: Ah, I see. Should I delete it then?